# Separar respuesta json en la vista Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, json

tengo una llamada ajax en una web Laravel, para traer datos dinámicos desde el controlador. Los datos los trae bien, pero mi pregunta es si hay manera de separar los elementos de la respuesta json que pertenece a comentarios.
La llamada ajax es:

```
      $('body').on('click','.listelement',function(e){

                    let html = '';
                    $('#elementbox').html(elementbox_html);
                    let row =  $(this);
                    let id= row.attr('id_element').replace('element', '');
                    let url = "{{ url('superadmin/ajax/logs/')}}/"+id+"/";
                    id_global = id;

                    $.ajax({
                        url:   url,
                        type:  'GET',
                        dataType: "json",

                        success:  function (data) {

                            console.log(data);

                            $('.delperm').css('display', 'block');


                            $('#detail_id').val(data.id);

                            user_name = data.user_name;
                            tipus_element = data.tipus_element;
                            accio = data.accio;
                            commentaris = data.commentaris;

                            $('#detall_1').text(user_name);
                            $('#detall_2').text(tipus_element);
                            $('#detall_3').text(accio);
                            $('#detall_4').text(commentaris);

                            $(".detall_element").show();

                        }
                    });
                });
```

La respuesta que quiero mostrar separada (pues en la vista sale tal cual) es:

```
    {"id":11,"status":1,"abreviatura":"Vm-1","last_change":"2020-04-29 09:41:34","created_at":"2020-04-29 09:41:24","updated_at":"2020-04-29 09:41:34","title":"Vermell edit","translations":[{"id":21,"color_id":11,"locale":"ca","title":"Vermell edit"},{"id":22,"color_id":11,"locale":"es","title":"Rojo"}]}
```

Gracias de antemano

Logré parsear el json así:

```
    JSON.parse(commentaris, function (k, v) {

         console.log(k +':'+ v );

         let comment = k +':'+ v +'  ';

         html +=comment;

         $('#detall_4').text(html);

      });
```

Pero en la vista se ve así:

```
    id:11 status:1 abreviatura:Vm-1 last_change:2020-04-29 09:41:34 created_at:2020-04-29 09:41:24 updated_at:2020-04-29 09:41:34 title:Vermell edit id:21 color_id:11 locale:ca title:Vermell edit 0:[object Object] id:22 color_id:11 locale:es title:Rojo 1:[object Object] translations:, :[object Object]
```

Habría alguna manera de que se viera cada elemento en una línea? Algo así:

```
    id:11 status:1 
    abreviatura:Vm-1 
    last_change:2020-04-29 09:41:34 
    created_at:2020-04-29 09:41:24 
    updated_at:2020-04-29 09:41:34 
    title:Vermell edit 
    id:21 
    color_id:11 
    locale:ca 
    title:Vermell edit 
    0:[object Object] 
    id:22 
    color_id:11 
    locale:es 
    title:Rojo 
    1:[object Object] 
    translations:, :[object Object]
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien... ¿que parte/atrbuto de ese objeto quieres mostrar y dónde?

Comment: Edité la pregunta, logré separar el json pero ahora me gustaría que no quedara todo junto. Puse un ejemplo de como necesito que quede. Gracias por responder

Comment: Esto se añade dinámicamente así a la web:

         let elementbox_html =
                    '                <p class="detall" id="detall_4"></p>';

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí solucionarlo. Era tan tonto... simplemente cambiar text() por html() en la salida, pude dar formato con etiquetas html sin que las imprima como string:

```
       JSON.parse(commentaris, function (k, v) {


           let comment ='<strong>'+ k +':</strong>'+ v + '<br/> ';

           html +=comment;


           $('#detall_4').html(html);

       });
```